# Can I make a route that does not map to a URL in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a bunch of routes in my routes.rb that look like this:

```
post 'events/form1'=> 'events#form1', :as => 'events_form1'
post 'events/form2'=> 'events#form2', :as => 'events_form2'
post 'events/form3'=> 'events#form3', :as => 'events_form3'
```

These controller actions process data from my forms. The user is never going to need to access these actions by URL so I wanted to do something like this:

```
post 'events#form1'
```

and then, in my form, write

```
<%= simple_form_for :something, :url => url_for{:controller => 'events', :action => 'form1'}, :method => "post" do |f| %>
```

This doesn't work because rails complains that the route is invalid. Is it possible to have a route without a url? If not, how can I clean up my routes file?

Answer (score 0):

The `simple_form_for` call still needs a URL, even if your users will never use it directly.

You can kind of see this in the code itself, in that one of the options you're sending to `simple_form_for` is an option for the URL to use:

```
:url => url_for{:controller => 'events', :action => 'form1'}
```